# Postgres - Return function in Case When Statement

Tags: postgresql, function, random

Hey I want to create a random number. When this random number already exist i want to call the `randomnumber` function again and again. In that case i need to return the `randomnumber` function inside in CASE WHEN statement.
It does not work. Still get error that number already exist. I want to create a random number for unique column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrandomnumber(integer, integer)
        RETURNS integer AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE
            start_int ALIAS FOR $1;
            end_int ALIAS FOR $2;
            name int;
        BEGIN
        name = trunc(random() * (end_int-start_int) + start_int);

        CASE WHEN (select count(alias) from drivers where alias = name limit 1) = 0

        THEN RETURN name;

        ELSE RETURN getrandomnumber(start_int, end_int);

        END CASE;
        END;

        $BODY$

        LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
        COST 100;
        ALTER FUNCTION getrandomnumber(integer, integer)
        OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: show table structure and sample data

Comment: Table contains an id, a name and an alias name. Id gets created by sequenzce, name is a varchar and alias is a bigint between 1 and 1000. This alias i want to create by the function. Alias column is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works correctly for me when run without concurrency, i.e. by one user at a time.

With:

```
CREATE TABLE drivers (alias integer);

INSERT INTO drivers(alias) VALUES (1),(2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...;
```

then

```
INSERT INTO drivers(alias) VALUES (getrandomnumber(1, 5));
```

works twice, then fails with infinite recursion.

---

Your function will not work correctly if it is called at the same time from multiple sessions. You must `LOCK TABLE drivers IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` or be prepared to handle unique violation errors.

I think what you really want is something more like a "random sequence" that doesn't repeat, e.g. [the pseudo-encrypt function](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt).

---

BTW, while:

```
(select count(alias) from drivers where alias = name limit 1) = 0
```

will work, you should probably try:

```
exists (select 1 from drivers where alias = name limit 1)
```

as it's generally faster.

Comment: Is there no way to use my function?

Comment: @Pauli Your function needs to be changed to use `IF ... THEN ... END IF` instead of `CASE ... WHEN ... END`. Otherwise it will work, it's just not a very good way to do what I think you are actually trying to do, and it won't work under concurrency. If you want to generate "random" but unique numbers, use the pseudo-encrypt function linked above, it's much better.

Comment: Ok i can use this pseudo-encrypt function, but i still got no unqiue random numbers. Do I still have to use the IF...THEN....END IF part out of my function? And how can i reduce the ouput to 6? I need a random number between 1 and 999999.

Comment: @Pauli `pseudo_encrypt` totally replaces your function, by generating unique pseudo-random numbers from a `SEQUENCE`. Just `CREATE SEQUENCE my_random_number_seed;` then `SELECT pseudo_encrypt(nextval('my_random_number_seed'))`. You can wrap this in a simple `LANGUAGE sql` function if you want.

Comment: @Pauli When used in conjunction with a `SEQUENCE`, yes, it does. If you believe otherwise, please post a new question (link to it here) showing exactly what you did to conclude that it is producing non-unique values, step by step.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! But one last questions. Is there a way so I can reduce the output to 6? I only want random numbers between 1 and 999999.

Comment: @CraigRinger Incorrect. `plpgsql` HAS `case  when` statements. Look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54460)

Comment: @alexpods Huh. Thankyou. I am indeed wrong about that and will correct the answer. I missed that in earlier reviews of the docs.

Comment: @Pauli Re setting the range from 1 to 999999 ... it might be possible by tweaking the cipher input values. I don't know enough about the cipher, honestly. You could always use your current approach with a `LOCK TABLE drivers IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` and iterate (WHILE loop) instead of recursing. Or just do what most people do - have your application handle the `unique_violation` error on duplicate key by re-trying the transaction.