# Reduce length of the pseudo-encrypt function ouput

Tags: postgresql

i have a question about [the pseudo-encrypt function for postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt).
Is there any way that I can reduce the output to 6? I really like this function and want to use it, but only need a output between 1 and 999999.

This question is related to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485571/postgres-return-function-in-case-when-statement). I want to use it to created unqiue numbers between 1 and 999999.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mod`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) on the generated value to generate number in range from `start_value` to `end_value`:

```
select start_value + mod(pseudo_encrypt(number), end_value - start_value + 1);
```

For your case this will be look like:

```
select 1 + mod(pseudo_encrypt(23452), 999999);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but when i use this select i have the unique-problem again. Its hard to test it with 999999 entries, but when i try it with for example 99. I have again the unqiue validation problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite straightforward to set an upper bound of 999999, as the algorithm operates on blocks of bits, so it's hard to get away from powers of two.

You can work around this by [cycle walking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking) - just try `encrypt(n)`, `encrypt(encrypt(n))`, `encrypt(encrypt(encrypt(n)))`... until you end up with a result in the range [1,999999]. In the interest of keeping the number of iterations to a minimum, you want to adjust the block size to get you as close to this range as possible.

This version will let you specify a range for the input/output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pseudo_encrypt(
  value INT8,
  min INT8 DEFAULT 0,
  max INT8 DEFAULT (2^62::NUMERIC)-1
) RETURNS INT8 AS
$$
DECLARE
  rounds CONSTANT INT = 3;
  L INT8[];
  R INT8[];
  i INT;
  blocksize INT;
  blockmask INT8;
  result INT8;
BEGIN
  max = max - min;
  value = value - min;
  IF NOT ((value BETWEEN 0 AND max) AND (max BETWEEN 0 AND 2^62::NUMERIC-1)) THEN
    RAISE 'Input out of range';
  END IF;

  blocksize = ceil(char_length(ltrim(max::BIT(64)::TEXT,'0'))/2.0);
  blockmask = (2^blocksize::NUMERIC-1)::INT8;
  result = value;
  LOOP
    L[1] = (result >> blocksize) & blockmask;
    R[1] = result & blockmask;
    FOR i IN 1..rounds LOOP
      L[i+1] = R[i];
      R[i+1] = L[i] # ((941083981*R[i] + 768614336404564651) & blockmask);
    END LOOP;
    result = (L[rounds]::INT8 << blocksize) | R[rounds];

    IF result <= max THEN
      RETURN result + min;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

I can't guarantee its correctness, but you can easily show that it maps [1,999999] back to [1,999999]:

```
SELECT i FROM generate_series(1,999999) s(i)
EXCEPT
SELECT pseudo_encrypt(i,1,999999) FROM generate_series(1,999999) s(i)
```